# Start the desktop application on the server using a browser and display the application page

Tags: java, web, desktop

I am trying to built a web project like a desktop.There are some button to start external software including the Javaswing project.

This javaswing project has been a jar with a external *config.ini* and located in server.When both the Jar package and the configuration file exist,it can start with 'java -jar ***.jar'.It's a GUI application and has window after start.

I want to start this javaswing project by request,and get its window and show this window in my web project.Finally,user can using this javaswing project by visiting web project(only click the button).

How can I implement this function？It seems like a webOS,but I don't know how to achieve this...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Perhaps you need [webswing](https://www.webswing.org/) ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.Due to performance limitations, it needs to be presented as its native form rather than a web application,just display its window on browser .Besides,these applications including other form like exe,py.So,webswing can't achieve it. @Abra

Comment: is not a good question